# send specific data to ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i want to post a variable data to ajax post this is my 
html code

```html
<tr>
                <td class="text-right">Payment ID:</td>
                <td>variable</td> // variable that i want to post
              </tr>
```

and this is my java script code

```js
var ajax_call = function() {
      $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"request-handler.php",
                    data:{
                    
                    data:"Payment ID"
                    
                    }
                });


};

var interval = 5000; // where X is your every X minutes

setInterval(ajax_call, interval);
```

now i want to post the variable that between td tags  in the ajaxpost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set an id on that cell so your js is easily readable, then just use jQuery to access the text.

```js
var ajax_call = function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "request-handler.php",
    data: {
      paymentId: $('#payment-id').text();
      // access this on the php server using: $_POST['paymentId'];
    }
  });
};

var interval = 5000; // where X is your every X minutes

setInterval(ajax_call, interval);
```

```html
<tr>
  <td class="text-right">Payment ID:</td>
  <td id="payment-id">variable</td>
  <!-- variable that i want to post -->
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr id="rowID">
  <td class="text-right">Payment ID:</td>
  <td>variable</td> // variable that i want to post
</tr>
```

and in your javascript

```
var ajax_call = function() {
      $.ajax({
           type:"post",
           url:"request-handler.php",
           data:{
                    var Row = document.getElementById("rowID");
var Cells = Row.getElementsByTagName("td");
                    data:Cells[1].innerText

                    }
                });


};
```

EDIT: You can directly use var cells = document.**getElementsByTagName**("td"); as well. OR set and id to cell
 `<tr >
      <td class="text-right">Payment ID:</td>
      <td id="columnID">variable</td> // variable that i want to post
    </tr>`

`data:{document.getElementById("columnID")}`

Comment: Whilst this should work, it seems a little overkill for this task. Surely adding an id to the td and using that as a selector would be more appropriate?

Comment: Also, if the OP is posting more than one item back, perhaps serialising form data would also be more appropriate?

Comment: Yes, that would be more appropriate, I have added that as an example in case OP wants to read more `td`

Comment: I only say this because the assumption is that the OP is probably new to coding js